# Compound type vs mixins in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, mixins, compound-type

readying about compound type in programming scala 2nd edition, and left with more question than answers.

When you declare an instance that combines several types, you get a compound type:

```scala
trait T1
trait T2
class C
val c = new C with T1 with T2  // c's type: C with T1 with T2
```

In this case, the type of `c` is `C with T1 with T2`. This is an alternative to declaring a type that extends `C` and mixes in `T1` and `T2`. Note that `c` is considered a subtype of all three types:

```scala
val t1: T1 = c
val t2: T2 = c
val c2: C  = c
```

The question that comes to mind is , why the alternative ? If you add something to a language it is supposed to add some value, otherwise it is useless. Hence, what's the added value of compound type and how does it compare to mixins i.e. **extend ... with ...**

Comment: It's the same thing. In the first case compiler will generate anonymous class that extends all the traits. Alternatively, you can generate the class yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixins and compound types are different notions:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html

vs.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/compound-types.html

Mixins are traits

```
trait T1
trait T2
class C
class D extends C with T1 with T2
val c = new D
```

Partial case of that is when an anonymous class is instead of `D`

```
trait T1
trait T2
class C
val c = new C with T1 with T2 // (*)
```

Compound types are types

```
type T = Int with String with A with B with C
```

Type of `c` in (*) is a compound type.

The notion of mixins is from the world of classes, inheritance, OOP etc. The notion of compound types is from the world of types, subtyping, type systems, type theory etc.

---

The authors of "Programming in Scala" mean that there is an alternative:

- either to introduce `D`

  (then `D` extends two mixins, namely `T1` and `T2`, type of `c` is `D`)
- or not

  (to use anonymous class instead of `D`, type of `c` is a compound type).

Comment: In Scala those two worlds do not represent a dichotomy and in fact intersect with the latter describing the former.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yeah, surely the worlds intersect (just don't coincide).

Comment: They correspond. At least that is the goal

Comment: @DmytroMitin why then would the author say `This is an alternative to declaring a type that extends C and mixes in T1 and T2. Note that c is considered a subtype of all three types:` this statement feel like saying an alternative to using extend with mixins

Comment: @MaatDeamon They mean that there is an alternative: either to introduce `D` (then `D` extends two mixins, namely `T1` and `T2`, type of `c` is `D`) or not (to use anonymous class instead of `D`, type of `c` is a compound type).

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's disputable what the goal is. From one side, static types exist to specify runtime behavior at compile time and to avoid dynamic-type inconsistencies. From other side, there is type-level programming where types have independent significance and the goal is to perform calculations on type level, formulate business logic in terms of types.